# AspNet MVC Identity - SendAsync HttpStatusCode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Using ASP.NET MVC5 with Microsoft.AspNet.Identity v2.2.1 (current latest release)

Is it possible to return the HttpStatusCode from this SendAsync email method?

It runs fine, sending an email.  The problem is when the service fails with a non 200 HttpStatusCode, it is swallowed. I would like the user to be notified if the email cannot be delivered.

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        var client = new RestClient
        {
            BaseUrl = new Uri("https://api.mailgun.net/v3"),
            Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api", GetMailGunKey())
        };
        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.AddParameter("domain", "mg.davestopmusic.com", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
        request.Resource = "{domain}/messages";
        request.AddParameter("from", "Dave Mateer <dave@davestopmusic.com>");
        request.AddParameter("to", message.Destination);
        request.AddParameter("subject", message.Subject);
        request.AddParameter("text", message.Body);
        request.AddParameter("html", message.Body);
        request.Method = Method.POST;

        var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
        int sc = (int) response.StatusCode;
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            // display the status code to the user
        }
    }
```

Email confirmation and password reset functionality modifications from here:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset

The temptation is to go to another Identity provider in hope it is more extensible:
https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Apr/29/Adding-minimal-OWIN-Identity-Authentication-to-an-Existing-ASPNET-MVC-Application

I do not need external based authenticaiton.

Perhaps I need another method that returns the StatusCode and somehow wire this up instead of SendAsync.

```
public Task<int> SendAsync2(IdentityMessage message)
{
    // blah
    int sc = (int) response.StatusCode;
    return Task.FromResult(sc);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using [Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/), so my process is a bit different, but what I do is throw an exception, and use some exception handling to display a message when redisplaying the form. Here's a simplified version of that:

1) Throw an exception if the status code isn't what you expected:

```
if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    // Create this exception at some point.
    // It doesn't need to do anything except inherit Exception
    throw new MyCustomEmailException();
}
```

2) Catch the exception in the action that calls into your email service:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(Models.PasswordResetForm model)
{
    try
    {
        // Call your email sending code...
    }
    catch(MyCustomEmailException ex)
    {
        // Remember to log the exception

        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "We're sorry, we could not complete this request. Please wait a moment and then try again");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

You might also consider offloading email sending to a separate process, like [Hangfire](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/best-practices.html), although that would require some refactoring (you'll need a method of recording whether an email was sent, so that you know if you need to retry).

Comment: Thanks Tieson - just what I needed!  Exception throwing solution works well.  Postal/Hangfire thoughts too great.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use other method to send request, something like this

```
client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => 
{
    int sc = (int)response.StatusCode;
    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        // display the status code to the user
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nguyen - the original call client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request) does work well.  Your code sample is doing a similar thing - interesting to see it rewritten.  It is how to handle response codes that is the issue.